# notifyListeners in provider not working cause use class inside provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

I had a Provider class "Provider_Controller", when i use all method in thats class it working properly with notifyListeners,
but when i put in class  "Provider_Chat" inside "Provider_Controller" notifyListeners not working properly event when data in "Provider_Chat"  be updated,

i'am using provider: ^5.0.0

```
class Provider_Controller with ChangeNotifier {
    Provider_Chat _provider_chat = new Provider_Chat();

    Provider_Chat get provider_chat => _provider_chat;
    set provider_chat(Provider_Chat pc) {
      try {
      _provider_chat = pc;
       notifyListeners();
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
  Model_User _user;
  Model_User get user => _user;
  set user(Model_User user) {
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<Model_User_Chat_Contact> _list_user_chat;

  List<Model_User_Chat_Contact> get list_user_chat => _list_user_chat;
  set list_user_chat(List<Model_User_Chat_Contact> new_list) {
    _list_user_chat = new_list;
    notifyListeners();
  }


}

class Provider_Chat {
  TextEditingController _textEditingController_message =
      TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController get textEditingController_message =>
      _textEditingController_message;
  set textEditingController_message(TextEditingController input) {
    _textEditingController_message = input;
  }

  List<Model_Chat> _list_chat;

  List<Model_Chat> get list_chat => _list_chat;
  set list_chat(List<Model_Chat> new_list) {
    try {
      _list_chat = new_list;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
}
```

ex:

```
Provider_Controller pc = Provider.of<Provider_Controller>(context);
```

access method inside "Provider_Controller" is still working.

```
pc.user  = new_user(); // notifyListeners working fine
```

but when.. access

```
pc.provider_chat.list_chat = new_list(); // the data still changed, but notifyListeners not working
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `pc.provider_chat.list_chat = new_list();` your'e accessing the Provider_Chat class setter which doesn't have `notifyListeners()` in it if you check it out (Because Provider_Chat is not a ChangeNotifer). If you want to update notifiers on it's update you can use a setter on the Provider_Controller which changes the Provider_Chat and notifies listeners like that:

```
class Provider_Controller with ChangeNotifier {
  ...
  set providerChatList(List<Model_Chat> new_list) {
    _provider_chat.list_chat = new_list;
    notifyListeners()
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, the data can updated, but notifyListeners still not working